# Haskell my recursion crashes

Tags: haskell, recursion

Hello I am beginner and I try to learn recursions in Haskell 
but my recursive function wont give me a solution and my pc freezes. Here is my function. I want that my function gets a number and it gets subtracted with 1. 
Everytime the number gets subtracted it will be added to the list which starts with 0. For example 
we 3 = [0,3,2,1]

```
we w 
   |w == 0 = []
   |w >0 = te [0] w w
   |w <0 = error "test"
   |otherwise = error "test"
   where
te (x:xs) f c = te (x:f:xs) (f-1) (c-1)
te (x:xs) f 0 = x:xs 
te (x:xs) 0 c = x:xs 
te (x:xs) 0 0 = x:xs
```

Comment: well, the first pattern of `te` will here always be matched, so you keep making the *list* larger,

Comment: how could i stop the recursion i tried it with f  0   0 c and 0 0

Comment: put them at the top of the `te` definition instead of at the bottom. It is not like in Java where the "most specific function is called". Haskell conceptually evaluates clauses top-to-bottom until one of these fires.

Comment: it worked now thanks

Comment: as far as I know, it probably produces the result in reverse: `[0,1,2,3]` instead of `[0,3,2,1]`.

Comment: Why not `we n = 0 : [n,n-1..1]`..?

Comment: Yet another case which would have been spotted by GHC, had the warnings been on. I'd strongly recommend to turn on warnings with the `-Wall` flag.

Comment: @Redu: I think the assignment is meant to make exercises on recursion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your function has some problems, although only is currently the reason why your program freezes:

1. `te (x:xs) f c = ...` is a pattern that matches *nearly* all possibilities: all calls with the first argument being a non-empty list will be match, the remaining clauses will never "fire", since these are subset patterns of the first clause; and
2. when we take the first clause, we will perform recursion with a list that is growing. There is no way we will get to the base cases (because of the first item), but we will eventually also run out of memory.

There are also some strange things with your function (that are not wrong, but not efficient or elegant):

1. you use `f` and `c` in the `te` function, but these always have the same value; and
2. you compare with `w > 0`, `w < 0` and `w == 0`, and an otherwise, this is weird since there is no way a value can not be greater than, not be less than and not be equal at the same time.

So perhaps we should return to the drawing board first. The first step is more or less a good one: we define the function `we` and we discriminate between three cases:

```
we w | w > 0 = ...
     | w == 0 = ...
     | otherwise = ...
```

apparently (this is not in the specifications you posted), we should error on `w < 0`, and return an empty list in case `w` is equal to zero, so:

```
we w | w > 0 = ...
     | w == 0 = []
     | otherwise = error "w is less than zero"
```

Now for `w > 0` we know we will produce a list that starts with `0` followed by something else, so we can write:

```
we w | w > 0 = 0 : ...
     | w == 0 = []
     | otherwise = error "w is less than zero"
```

so we construct a list `(_:_)` with `0` as head. Now the rest is a call to a recursive function (for instance `te`):

```
we w | w > 0 = 0 : te w
     | w == 0 = []
     | otherwise = error "w is less than zero"
    where te n = ...
```

Now for `te` there are two possibilities: `n > 0`, in which case we "*emit*" `n`, and perform recursion on the decrement of `n`; or in case `n <= 0`, we terminate (so we produce an empty list):

```
we w | w > 0 = 0 : te w
     | w == 0 = []
     | otherwise = error "w is less than zero"
    where te n | n > 0 = n : te (n-1)
               | otherwise = []
```

and that's it!